# Is it a noun or not?

Tags: code-challenge, decision-problem, natural-language, test-battery

Given a string as input, determine whether it is a noun or not.

You will be scored on the 1000 most common English words, by how many you correctly label as a noun or not.

The program or function which correctly classifies the most of those words in 50 bytes or less will win.

## Nouns

A noun is a word that represents a thing, typically. It gets more complex, but that's the basic idea.

In cases where a word could either be a noun or some other part of speech, I classified it as a noun, even if that's a rare usage. Or actually, I let [this site](http://www.talkenglish.com/vocabulary/top-1500-nouns.aspx) do it for me.

The words you'll be scored on are these [1000 common words](https://github.com/isaacg1/words/blob/master/common-words.txt), which are from [simple Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_1000_basic_words), with "two" and "once" added. Of those, these are the [586 nouns](https://github.com/isaacg1/words/blob/master/common-nouns.txt), and these are the [414 non-nouns](https://github.com/isaacg1/words/blob/master/common-non-nouns.txt). You can find all three lists [here](https://github.com/isaacg1/words). Note that all of these inputs are in lower case. These lists are final - don't try to argue grammar.

Your program will be considered correct if it outputs a [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) result on an input which is a noun, and a falsy result on an input which is not a noun.

**Subtleties:**

Programs must have a deterministic output. If you want to use randomness, seed it. Programs are not allowed to use built-in noun lists or other built-in part-of-speech functionality.

**Examples:**

```
a: noun
act: noun
active: noun
about: non-noun
above: non-noun
across: non-noun
```

Please indicate what your program's success rate is in your answer. The program or function of at most 50 bytes with the highest success rate wins. In case of a tie, lowest byte count will determine a winner. Good luck!

Answer (score 13):

### JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes, <s>622</s> <s>630</s> 633

Just to get the ball rolling. Returns `1` for nouns, `0` for non-nouns.

```js
s=>2552>>s.length&/^[bcdf-mp-tvwy]/.test(s)
```

#### How?

We bet on *noun* if both following conditions are met:

1. The word length is 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 11. This is done by right-shifting the binary number 100111111000 (2552 as decimal).
2. The word starts with one of these letters: `bcdfghijklmpqrstvwy`

Comment: Just as I was about to comment, with JS specifically in mind, that the byte limit was far too restrictive, you post this! I was thinking, without having looked at the list, that a better score than 586 might just be possible by testing the first letter or 2 in each word. Nicely done :)

Comment: An explanation would be nice, for people less familiar with Javascript. As far as I can tell, this checks whether the word length is 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 11, and the word also starts with one of a set of letters?

Comment: @isaacg That's correct. Explanation added.

Comment: Note that the character class `[bcdf-mp-tvwy]` is equivalent to the class `[^aenouxz]`. A change would save 4 bytes, which could be capitalized on.

Comment: @fireflame241 Very true. And that can even be shortened to `[^aenouz]` because we don't have any word starting with a `x`.

Comment: I wonder (again, without having looked at the list): could you use the bytes fireflame saved you to add a check for the 2nd letter and increase your score. I'm coming off the back of an 80 hour week so I'm not even sure that makes sense to *me*! Just thought it was worth the suggestion.

Comment: I think `y` does not improve the score at all (I think `bcdfghijklmpqrstvw` suffice). Maybe you can do something with that byte.

Comment: @Shaggy I was too tired to work on that one any further yesterday evening. Rick has since done a much better work in JS, so I've switched to Jelly instead. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 bytes, score 693

```
s=>!/^([aouz]|th|..$)|e.+[ey]|[flo].r|a.p/.test(s)
```

Just looking for any possible patterns that non-nouns have that nouns don't.

Non-nouns more often contain:

1. **a, o, u,** or **z** as the first letter.
2. **th** as the first two letters.
3. Two letters only.  [Think pronouns (me, we, us, he, it) and prepositions (of, to, in, on, by, at, up, ...).]
4. **e**, followed by one or more letters, followed by **e** or **y**.
5. **f, l,** or **o**, followed by any letter, followed by **r**.
6. **a**, followed by any letter, followed by **p**.

**Snippet:**

```js
var nouns = ['a','act','active','activity','age','air','amount','answer','anything','apple','area','arm','army','art','ask','attack',
             'baby','back','bad','bag','ball','bank','base','basket','bath','bear','beautiful','bed','bedroom','beer','bell','big','bird','birth','birthday','bit','bite','black','block','blood','blow','blue','board','boat','body','bone','book','border','bottle','bottom','bowl','box','boy','branch','brave','bread','break','breakfast','bridge','brother','brown','brush','burn','business','bus','buy',
             'cake','call','can','candle','cap','car','card','care','carry','case','cat','catch','chair','chance','change','chicken','child','chocolate','choice','city','class','clock','clothes','cloud','coffee','coat','cold','comfortable','common','computer','condition','control','cook','corner','cost','count','country','course','cover','crash','cross','cry','cup','cut',
             'dance','dark','daughter','day','dead','deep','desk','dinner','direction','dish','dog','door','double','draw','dream','dress','drink','drive','drop','dust','duty',
             'ear','earth','east','eat','education','effect','egg','end','equal','entrance','escape','evening','event','examination','example','exercise','eye',
             'face','fact','fail','fall','family','farm','father','fat','fault','fear','feed','feel','female','few','fight','fill','film','finger','finish','fire','fish','fix','floor','flower','fly','fold','food','foot','football','force','form','freedom','friend','front','fruit','fun','funny','future',
             'game','garden','gate','general','gift','give','glad','glass','go','god','gold','good','grandfather','grandmother','grass','great','green','ground','group',
             'hair','half','hall','hand','hat','hate','head','heavy','heart','height','hello','help','hide','high','hit','hold','hole','holiday','home','hope','horse','hospital','hotel','house','hour','hurry','husband','hurt',
             'ice','idea','if','increase','inside','iron','invite','island','it',
             'job','join','juice','jump',
             'keep','key','kill','kind','king','kitchen','knee','knife',
             'ladder','lady','land','laugh','lead','leave','leg','length','lesson','let','letter','library','lie','life','light','lip','list','listen','lock','long','look','love','low','luck',
             'machine','main','make','male','man','many','map','mark','market','matter','meal','meat','medicine','meet','member','mention','method','middle','milk','mind','minute','miss','mistake','mix','model','moment','money','month','morning','most','mother','mountain','mouth','move','music',
             'name','nation','nature','neck','net','news','newspaper','night','noise','north','nose','nothing','notice','number',
             'object','offer','office','oil','one','opposite','orange','order','other','outside','page','pain','paint','pair','paper','parent','park','part','partner','party','pass','past','path','pay','peace','pen','people','period','person','piano','pick','picture','piece','pin','place','plane','plant','plastic','plate','play','plenty','point','police','pool','position','possible','potato','power','present','press','price','private','prize','problem','produce','promise','public','pull','push','put',
             'queen','question','quiet',
             'radio','rain','raise','reach','read','record','red','remove','rent','repair','repeat','reply','report','rest','restaurant','result','return','rice','rich','ride','ring','rise','road','rock','room','round','rule','run','rush',
             'sad','safe','sail','salt','sand','save','school','science','search','seat','second','sell','sentence','serve','sex','shake','shape','share','she','shine','ship','shirt','shoe','shoot','shop','shoulder','show','sick','side','signal','silly','silver','simple','single','sing','sink','sister','size','skill','skin','skirt','sky','sleep','slip','smell','smile','smoke','snow','sock','soft','son','sound','soup','south','space','special','speed','spell','spend','sport','spread','spring','square','stand','star','start','station','stay','steal','step','still','stomach','stop','store','storm','story','street','structure','student','study','stupid','subject','substance','sugar','summer','sun','support','surprise','sweet','swim',
             'table','talk','taste','tea','teach','team','tear','telephone','television','tell','tennis','test','thing','tie','title','today','toe','tomorrow','tonight','tool','tooth','top','total','touch','town','train','travel','tree','trouble','trust','try','turn','type',
             'uncle','unit','use','usual',
             'vegetable','village','voice','visit',
             'wait','wake','walk','wash','watch','water','way','wear','weather','wedding','week','weight','welcome','west','wheel','while','white','wife','will','win','wind','window','wine','winter','wish','woman','wonder','word','work','world','worry',
             'yard','yesterday','you','young',
             'two'],
   nonNouns=['about','above','across','add','afraid','after','again','ago','agree','all','alone','along','already','always','am','an','and','angry','another','any','anyone','anytime','appear','are','around','arrive','as','at','aunt','autumn','away',
             'be','bean','behave','before','begin','behind','below','besides','best','better','between','bleed','boil','born','borrow','both','breathe','bright','bring','build','busy','but','by',
             'careful','careless','central','century','certain','chase','cheap','cheese','children','choose','circle','clever','clean','clear','climb','cloth','cloudy','close','coin','collect','colour','comb','compare','come','complete','continue','cool','copper','corn','correct','contain','cupboard',
             'dangerous','decide','decrease','deer','depend','destroy','develop','die','different','difficult','dirty','discover','do','down','dry','duck',
             'each','early','earn','easy','eight','either','electric','elephant','else','empty','enemy','enjoy','enough','enter','even','ever','every','everyone','exact','everybody','except','excited','expect','expensive','explain','extremely',
             'false','famous','far','fast','fever','find','fine','first','fit','five','flag','flat','float','flour','fool','for','foreign','forest','forget','forgive','fork','fox','four','free','freeze','fresh','friendly','from','full','furniture','further',
             'gentleman','get','goat','goodbye','grave','gray','grow','gun',
             'hammer','happen','happy','hard','have','he','healthy','hear','heaven','hen','her','here','hers','hill','him','his','hobby','hot','how','hundred','hungry',
             'i','important','in','into','introduce','invent','is','its',
             'jelly','just',
             'knock','know',
             'lamp','large','last','late','lately','lazy','leaf','learn','left','lend','less','like','lion','little','live','lonely','lose','lot','lower',
             'marry','may','me','mean','measure','million','modern','monkey','moon','more','much','must','my',
             'narrow','near','nearly','need','needle','neighbour','neither','never','new','next','nice','nine','no','noble','none','nor','not','now',
             'obey','ocean','of','off','often','old','on','only','open','or','our','out','over','own',
             'pan','pencil','pepper','per','perfect','petrol','photograph','pig','pink','please','pleased','pocket','poison','polite','poor','popular','pour','pretty','prevent','prince','prison','probably','proper','protect','provide','punish','pupil',
             'quick','quite',
             'rainy','ready','real','really','receive','remember','remind','right','rob','rubber','rude','ruler',
             'same','say','scissors','see','seem','send','seven','several','shade','shadow','sharp','sheep','sheet','shelf','short','should','shout','silence','similar','since','sit','six','slow','small','so','soap','some','someone','something','sometimes','soon','sorry','speak','spoon','stamp','steam','stone','strange','strong','successful','such','sudden','suitable','sunny','sure','sword',
             'take','tall','taxi','ten','terrible','than','that','the','their','then','there','therefore','these','thick','thin','think','third','this','though','threat','three','tidy','to','together','too','tram','true','twice',
             'ugly','under','understand','until','up','useful','usually',
             'very',
             'want','warm','was','waste','we','weak','were','well','wet','what','when','where','which','who','why','wide','wild','wire','wise','with','without',
             'yell','yet','your',
             'zero','zoo',
             'once'];

f=
s=>!/^([aouz]|th|..$)|e.+[ey]|[flo].r|a.p/.test(s)

//truthy:
tnoun = 0;
nouns.forEach(s=>tnoun += f(s));
console.log('Nouns: ' + tnoun + ' correct');

//falsy:
tnonNoun = 0;
nonNouns.forEach(s=>tnonNoun += !f(s));
console.log('Non-nouns: ' + tnonNoun + ' correct');
console.log('Total: ' + (tnoun + tnonNoun) + ' correct');
```

Comment: I believe you can save a byte by changing the first regex to `/h|n/` (or by doing `/^.[hn]/.test(s)`), and another by changing `s[2]>''` to either `!!s[2]` or `2 in s`.

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions. I can use your suggestions *and* combine the two tests to save a bunch of bytes, which allowed me to add code to improve my score.

Comment: Isn't `a.p` redundant since you already have `[aouz]`?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, the **a** in `[aouz]` is matched only when at the beginning of the string.  For whatever reason, testing for `a.p` *anywhere* in the string improves the score.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 48 bytes, score 731

This is my first ever answer in Jelly and I went to a lot of trouble putting this together. Ah well ... that was fun. :-)

```
O‘ḅ⁹%⁽€Oæ»4“Ạ$ⱮẊḲḲLÑMṆụ⁻ẉṂ`ŻvḤæɠ5ṭȯƁU*×TdƲḥ`’æ»Ḃ
```

*1 byte saved thanks to @JonathanAllan*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9qZWxsef//T@KAmOG4heKBuSXigb3igqxPw6bCuzTigJzhuqAk4rGu4bqK4biy4biyTMORTeG5huG7peKBu@G6ieG5gmDFu3bhuKTDpsmgNeG5rcivxoFVKsOXVGTGsuG4pWDigJnDpsK74biC////YmVk)

#### Breakdown and test suites

- [Non-nouns](https://tio.run/##PVbLjh01EP2XCDYoS/iLoCyAFUKKu7u62xm33fgxPZ1VJhIg2LECJBZZkKwCKKxmMmKTERF8xr0/MpTP8Y00U@e0r1226@V6LM7td3cPj09/Plx9c7y8/vB4@ffx2auHty/f3nx8fPrr4c3zD46v/zi8@eFw9Zf@Pbj98dPD9beHmxfHy5vDm@8P188e/XNzfrj67fblf88/OVz//u@f7y6/@Oj2p8@Hd7rgxaPj01@qssPVs7vb71T121ef3X9wd/flPdOFku/dr3guFfsYUqpkGKoco7EkWWLFyVgPDJBRsMo5yOCl4QSMYoYdbDM7tC5VQIGHWj9FTPAhz9zA83tvuvye7QK2rmIwI@IzhkIVMVoeHRvgMsUTclmwl@6u0AkEtu9kNuf8HkMkmWz7xUJxJy5swGQHSWQZkGkMJZsIFjkRrAnWAaInRKrQ21VQe@g1wew0ZxLYqivWQUFJOCqc0lXa633H4hpzAu/04nM0rrECG/YSM53TzyYJUMxKlDagu0ThnBA4ZmPvQJyc41pKYKOK/LZLB@Q1FAvcqoQqArcNzkmfyULB0sCVYVnpNmUNVieZ1GfrC2nAlYK6mqsj9cZ40utPVyxrF0ysJhs0iESjodplkF59RaLGTqRQNsgq8Kv6Msewg52rj6uFBouZdhxFzZMbt31x5DFjvk19oI2GALHVswww/1D6MwUx/QyIbid6ANwqzetiW7RLNVi0Pek6G@wtDgeXZcW24mUhPg7EUCZs4hmHeg1PaF84EJBZJBcG9sNQF@A8uehlzSQ2I3rlYqWdK/GJaaXc0eZykaMsgnuNhmcczULLjwiV0SBDxnaUkZmkgLk28ldLCfWjMxMBgy6cEPEzMiI0RSnVgL4xqgpxkhNpCkM8A1xAUg3LVIUnjaQZaDUmeKEYam3STMOGJXqreSXkzVuTGtzJguTgthOPO4UwdHudPEWWFcUdgPyfSl0ym2WBnrnWMt/IDkQkt5I0UxiX550sEujmuUkORk6O1Qea3Q6wQGIodKgic8iQ9TSzFs4Ihytj/bX1f1mDVhBEIPxtfQ6EGDS6Bfyc6QHlNlf5uD5fFQtccuYDEkGxbubMsgLUUUBMUm9LA6x15glAzEhA1jgZMZl520qfs2dYagOm2Jwdv2G7@gRRI0uTw721kMNciz4WOxBSIOBOhUR3L2pE6l7CIJHEnwlWhPYDZxak@sJ7I0W9aRXf02n@VAc834cKOK6vpaBjdPr35cC3vPFCHRdVsbcwvWcS@QDRUUtoY1iEq9LqocN5Q8/bhRGCMiN@Ap4bXCd4HDEwJqGLB2Nr0Coea90KfTqzx0O3SivV7@XICrKKBg1maOQFzYa1mmq1E6SvAaIPAAs0ST3OqqGDvFqDTTjbGtTDmBRwsDWsxRkynHGN@hrvJC02V31TYTIlTUsMnekcp4V21hhyO2sM53w11uItCsNaVtzv62IRzIo4hXZD6E9OjY2ia@D43QsDsVbKpcNOSlkHT4@@nqbK0rXfCzaPxeEzGQRmQoym3qYUkN0JNUzlAoDG1Ep/RfYDaTbQVhGhoCSuQJETZqIbgZr1xIKYqAQDVhMPdkxWkwJGT/Y0whm1xia2SWlhF5gCBBqPxNe@AiO1sjyz5QHX3g53Y2LpTZGfSVu9M2Abz6wiKQs6yJSbOm2C/NQYm85U@l4LBTumxAxNZRhoJnWjYeqk4uHJlvVpCyjB2aC6ZN4lm4taGZkx@tZGy8V5RhooZADHxEYif2NpBrYWU3kiMqqqJRq0T56BpTvP7ZnPc@0bG8F6i@BDddbkklY9csBAhIlyREuVN1aPMiE@tfJjKlCtiiDSbhnBXqqJS2rdZkmlBXXrJzY@DZuJCyBRIi82Cjht48U3gQk3BNtGS220zdZss6kdZmCAxC7MxI3t8GY50SYC@s8KDNGde@zYY2dBeKK9YAUYI9Rw/ep/) correctly identified as non-nouns: 265 / 414 (64%)
- [Nouns](https://tio.run/##RVfLriQ5Ef2XFmxGs4S/GDQLYIWQJm@mM9O3bIfbj8quWXW3BAh2rACJxSyYWfEQrPohNlwxgs@o@yN3wudE3ZFKPpEuOxyOt@9dCJenp88fX//x@u5Xj2/e//Dxzb8f3/7184dv/vPxR4@v/3z98NUPHv/59@uH313f/Ut/nz38/ifX97@@fvz68c3H64ffXt@//eK/H8/Xd395@Ob/X/34@v5v//vHt29@/snDH362fKsbvv7i8fWfBrPru7dPD79R1j/99LOnp1@8mF58@mKaG0d/djfCt8sgN0z4MsYoPWFhqofDTLq03adtkDkHLC0OHEvkCCYFu@ppjK1N8yDuprsLwL4WjBvGEACJ/1RHOLkGou0D3FQIvfm1Y4NbOBaRCMpxCdl58PZlIZDLwGWCIL5xxGnBxApyQ1mIB6BjlUzkJhP2ygJGkvinYKeUhWJIa8EZQfnkgGDyCiP2linNOwmY4k7VuRiebrhOFecVv2xcJG3nIUWOBOwVbHrBZ68@uVpJYhynzdPJAaCgeUocl8DZjLFwXAj8pxRur/xsHCH4vNNZFNPsjNhI@PnkEqkAfrvMEqbGf8VzPR1vDhPknc0CinpHm@nYLevqsIPqV1acjquUNt3xFhKjJBK5NyhplrT45m06tSK4Pu01S0m2qpIrfR7Ia0svvLicubJMUPZchCJzWYf@@ti8mC6WqZwAfdspC31voZEX5zIAkbL4REkWX9xs8i4eRy2yYRT8L52XXcp0ANwUiZBnKR6RpHjmMsExHRdcOvTNcNIRceHoYQ6KdUtX6/J8pzpHsnDbkMClIbd72aeAr1bspq6q/4A4u8QMMSjsfDVFn54Z6hczh3vlyuyhWXcZ4zrNBg3gAyAQog8XEMg062QRsE5c3AOQ11I/WQjY6@KEE1c31LV6NQaQnH0AQxWaDH2izlcP719vXyNq10ATKDIjrhSKrrgyaSg0A0tt6qC8mlD4ovIJKU@VrkWgrLV05KW1J44J/HvrEGabIkGTTAKBYNqceg5Msvm1AWD5LcDPNoutTTBgihJvlHhTMy7PKsVXlO@/uLnQOxR5dNEIWYwY/mWJYJ/CSggArNmxdae0O71f4Xwhol7szgyzawIXIvj6Bbv0XwCWUHwFR/AMrF0iJzKBgbtLzb5BP7s0R@z2V4fQnSlu7/XOJO4QijlKJRhFzo@L@TSrJrDZp0rZfIFv@3RmOfE1kAuEvZc7jH6sue9ked/juNyJKeDkxukneuTJY@@JYXTymmih8VNC@jslvw5U27LSKHEBYFsYyWYgtawAVwhuw5i2xn9rhcwBRVZH5qfgtRJBFcFjm51lpgk@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@oNpl4m21ZZuotrbF7t8go4nG5V6MPFJBNKxLxj7f@tHpUOPRdUUOuLK9bXCcmssrOoE86tTJuVabJqXwrj1VkrMwSpWp8gSuW1qhsNJQhoeRjveWkhFzfyRd2ZPRSzYSFyZL5SzAToqO7CWTYRivxXemDIKTkyaqU3W9RVvyXkw6ol5EJks1q9tVv6ItieCQIZ1GYL4WHVipBiIlCsE7gGlqvKOlCjaUDzKPZG4YUTRaR5qqAlYTBWM1Jlz1AtGWo2owKzmz0vktnDKQb75kbzpZrNLZWwC2lXSv02M2lDMzigEc3vlcJtGmuIImRpdnN9rdHxleIfYnzZvg3k/sJao0S/JZXa@sKAGBSX9ewhT7/lW6WGkLxy3yhmj5GGgOPWnm837SWb3@sznAcefghye/Roa3MCVCSLhmalWfQ2Pg4aO2PtflzemdgHffaVOmlUs3qytr8gEKu34tHQDTTPJ20TtltN@KWFr8DkTW7lqDGMFGBgarIJu7AmnbLx9dos8bTxCMb/BZ2OvtTspaMKpjhQvCWKdkFY9TQHIrot9nW98olydpu7qems9mV1Otvbc9x@7DkmA7jvQXUefOUd9tBVhHkO3PygOhWsAh5uWagqtRG239rZw4WZbelBnR473yXHzrBRhN0O9loH3fCASg62JgOg4INJQ8Gk4evkEPZOh2YmzjNVK5wIwT6hwAvf9xc3Yp@mvEjnSHMf8uKX3wE) correctly identified as nouns: 466 / 586 (79.5%)

#### How?

We first compute a hash of the input string by:

- converting it to an integer by interpreting each code point as a base-256 digit
- applying modulo 4080 (chosen as the most efficient value with no more than 12 bits)
- keeping the 8 most significant bits of the result

This leaves us with an index in [0 ... 255] and thus divides all words into 256 groups.

For each group of words, we pre-compute a binary flag which is `1` if the group contains more nouns than non-nouns, and `0` otherwise. This leads to a 256-bit number ***N*** that we're going to use as a lookup-table. We store it as a base-250 encoded string.

Below is the binary representation of ***N***.

```
1000011000001011000101111011111001001101110010101101110010001101
0000010001101010010111110001110010010101110110110010111111010000
0001111010011110000110101011111000011110111011010011011110101100
1010010110101111000010101000101100000001110110100011111000101010
```

Which can be stored as `` “Ạ$ⱮẊḲḲLÑMṆụ⁻ẉṂ`ŻvḤæɠ5ṭȯƁU*×TdƲḥ`’ `` in Jelly.

Hence the code:

```
O‘ḅ⁹%⁽€Oæ»4“Ạ$ⱮẊḲḲLÑMṆụ⁻ẉṂ`ŻvḤæɠ5ṭȯƁU*×TdƲḥ`’æ»Ḃ    main link

O                                                   convert the input string to a list of
                                                    code points
 ‘                                                  increment each of them
  ḅ⁹                                                convert from base 256 to an integer
    %⁽€O                                            modulo 4080
        æ»4                                         drop the 4 least significant bits
           “Ạ$ⱮẊḲḲLÑMṆụ⁻ẉṂ`ŻvḤæɠ5ṭȯƁU*×TdƲḥ`’æ»     right shift N by this amount
                                               Ḃ    test the least significant bit
```

Comment: Nice job! Save a byte to boot with ``O‘ḅ⁹%⁽€Oæ»4“Ạ$ⱮẊḲḲLÑMṆụ⁻ẉṂ`ŻvḤæɠ5ṭȯƁU*×TdƲḥ`’æ»Ḃ`` (also note you can use the footer on TIO, I'd go with `Ç€¬S,L` and `Ç€S,L` for your two test suites.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 50 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 763

<sup>Using a hash now (much like [Arnauld's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138810/53748))</sup>

```
OP%⁽Wpị“!ḋGẠ⁻Ṭȥʋt|Ḥ\⁾°½İ@G2ḂƑ½ịʂ¶ɦḲ⁷³Hz~⁵p9)⁹ƙ¿’B¤
```

**[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9qZWxsef//T1Al4oG9V3Dhu4vigJwh4biLR@G6oOKBu@G5rMilyot0fOG4pFzigb7CsMK9xLBARzLhuILGkcK94buLyoLCtsmm4biy4oG3wrNIen7igbVwOSnigbnGmcK/4oCZQsKk////dmVnZXRhYmxl)**

250 / 414 for [Non-Nouns](https://tio.run/##PVY9jx01FP0tRKJASkVHh2hCgQQSBQVQeGbuzDjrsQd/7OysEMqmoUhFGYmCIlCliEDAhiggPVAE@Rf7/shyfY5finfPGT/72r5fvvfFuf329uNP3j5evfxsvXnx6Pjg@7durh/du/njh@PVi5vnT//98fWj/PXN9ZMvjld/Hp4dXv7z7P17795cP3z13eGlLnj98PDbfz/dXP98vPr98MuHl98cr35d33vnePX81ePDX8cHjz84PLn9@9vjw6eHp5/e/ej29vM7pgsl37lb8Vwq9jGkVMkwVDlGY0myxIqTsR4YIKNglXOQwUvDCRjFDDvYZnZoXaqAAg@1foqY4EOeuYHn9950@T3bBWxdxWBGxGcMhSpitDw6NsBliifksmAv3V2hEwhs38lszvk9hkgy2faPheJOXNiAyQ6SyDIg0xhKNhEsciJYE6wDRE@IVKG3q6D20GuC2WnOJLBVV6yDgpJwVDilq7TX@47FNeYE3unF52hcYwU27CVmOqefTRKgmJUobUB3icI5IXDMxt6BODnHtZTARhX5bZcOyGsoFrhVCVUEbhuckz6ThYKlgSvDstJtyhqsTjKpz9YX0oArBXU1V0fqjfGk15@uWNYumFhNNmgQiUZDtcsgvfqKRI2dSKFskFXgV/VljmEHO1cfVwsNFjPtOIqaJzdu@@LIY8Z8m/pAGw0BYqtnGWD@ofRnCmL6GRDdTvQAuFWa18W2aJdqsGh70nU22FscDi7Lim3Fy0K8H4ihTNjEMw71Gp7QvnAgILNILgzsh6EuwHly0cuaSWxG9MrFSjtX4hPTSrmjzeUiR1kE9xoNzziahZYfESqjQYaM7SgjM0kBc23kv5YS6kdnJgIGXTgh4mdkRGiKUqoBfWNUFeIkJ9IUhngGuICkGpapCpeNpBloNSZ4oRhqbdJMw4Yleqt5JeTNW5Ma3MmC5OC2E487hTB0e508RZYVxR2A/J9KXTKbZYGeudYy38gORCS3kjRTGJfnnSwS6Oa5SQ5GTo7VB5rdDrBAYih0qCJzyJD1NLMWzgiHK2P9tfW3rEErCCIQ/rY@B0IMGt0Cfs70gHKbq7xfH66KBS458wGJoFg3c2ZZAeooICapt6UB1jpzCRAzEpA1TkZMZt620ufsGZbagCk2Z8dv2K4@QdTI0uRwby3kMNeij8UOhBQIuFMh0d2LGpG6lzBIJPFnghWh/cGZBam@8N5IUW9axfd0mj/VAc/3oQKO62sp6Bid/k058C1vvFDHRVXsLUzvmUQ@QHTUEtoYFuGqtHrocN7Q83ZhhKDMiJ@A5wbXCR5HDIxJ6OLB2Bq0isdat0Kfzuzx0K3SSvUbObKCrKJBgxkaeUGzYa2mWu0E6WuA6APAAk1Sj7Nq6CCv1mATzrYG9TAmBRxsDWtxhgxnXKO@xjtJi81V31SYTEnTEkNnOsdpoZ01htzOGsM5X421eIvCsJYV9/uqWASzIk6h3RD6k1Njo@gaOH73wkCslXLpsJNS1sHTo6@nqbJ07f@CzWNx@EwGgZkQo6m3KQVkd0INU7kAoDG10l@R/UCaDbRVRCgoiStQ5ISZ6EagZj2xICYqwYDVxIMdk9WkgNGTPY1wRq2xiW1SWtgFpgCBxiPxta/ASK0sz2x5wLW3w92YWHpT5GfSVu8M2MYzq0jKgg4y5aZOmyA/NcamM5W@10LBjikxQ1MZBppJ3WiYOql4eLJlfdoCSnA2qC6Zd8nmolZGZoy@tdFycZ6RBgoZwDGxkcj/WJqBrcVUnoiMqmqJBu2TZ2DpznN75vNc@8ZGsN4i@FCdNbmkVY8cMBBhohzRUuWN1aNMiE@t/JgKVKsiiLRbRrCXauKSWrdZUmlB3fqJjU/DZuICSJTIi40CTtt48U1gwg3BttFSG22zNdtsaocZGCCxCzNxYzu8WU60iYD@swJDdOceO/bYWRAutResAGOEGq5f/g8)
513 / 586 for [Nouns](https://tio.run/##RVc9jy43Ff4tXIkiUio6uogmFEggUVAAxeyMZ8b72j6@/njnvlGEsrehuBVlJAqKQJUiAgE3RDdIC4og/2L3j2yOn@e8m8bPGY99fHy@fetCuDw9/fwXP3y8e/er/PDVm8dP/viDh7dvPnz4158e7756@PLz//352zft44e3n/3m8e7r@y/u3/33iw8@/NHD29ff/OH@nW749vX9P/7/l4e3f328@@f933760e8e7/6ef/ze492X33x6/@/HTz79yf1nT//5/ePrz3/5/s@enn79Ynrx/otpbhz92V0J3y6D3DDhyxij9ISFqR4OM@nSdp@2QeYcsLQ4cCyRI5gU7KqnMbY2zYO4mW4uAPtaMG4YQwAk/qmOcHINRNsHuKkQevNrxwa3cCwiEZTjErLz4O3LQiCXgcsEQXzjiNOCiRXkirIQD0DHKpnITSbslQWMJPGnYKeUhWJIa8EZQfnkgGDyCiP2linNOwmY4kbVuRierrhOFecVv2xcJG3nIUWOBOwVbHrBZ68@uVpJYhynzdPJAaCgeUocl8DZjLFwXAj8Uwq3V342jhB83uksiml2Rmwk/HxyiVQAv11mCVPjX/FcT8ebwwR5Z7OAot7RZjp2y7o67KD6lRWn4yqlTTe8hcQoiUTuDUqaJS2@eZtOrQiuT3vNUpKtquRKnwfy2tILLy5nriwTlD0Xochc1qG/PjYvpotlKidA33bKQt9baOTFuQxApCw@UZLFFzebvIvHUYtsGAX/pfOyS5kOgJsiEfIsxSOSFM9cJjim44JLh74ZTjoiLhw9zEGxbulqXZ7vVOdIFm4bErg05HYv@xTw1Yrd1FX1HxBnl5ghBoWdr6bo0zND/WLmcK9cmT006y5jXKfZoAF8AARC9OECAplmnSwC1omLewDyWuonCwF7XZxw4uqGulavxgCSsw9gqEKToU/U@erh/ev1a0TtGmgCRWbElULRFVcmDYVmYKlNHZRXEwpfVD4h5anStQiUtZaOvLT2xDGBf28dwmxTJGiSSSAQTJtTz4FJNr82ACy/BfjZZrG1CQZMUeKNEm9qxuVZpfiK8v0XNxd6hyKPLhohixHDvywR7FNYCQGANTu27pR2p/crnC9E1IvdmWF2TeBCBF@/YJf@BWAJxVdwBM/A2iVyIhMYuLvU7Bv0s0tzxG6/OoTuTHF7rzcmcYdQzFEqwShyflzMp1k1gc0@VcrmC3zbpzPLia@BXCDsrdxg9GPNbSfL2x7H5U5MASc3Tj/RI08ee08Mo5PXRAuNnxLS3yn5daDalpVGiQsA28JINgOpZQW4QnAbxrQ1/q0VMgcUWR2Zn4LXSgRVBI9tdpaZJviMsTYDCGYpOwgEDkysQXguCmjoWBEnLQWolnGCNiIrksVnnDgHn4@oR5EZdAAEjZMJGh3sGemU0S1@Ns6OC128sYXJUk90bYe7R7@w5mlOAXcqXKE3TsPjFZrJh@CPssB3okRmNq00sJsilBq1ltBokcXkOYjQSdmVpdti6CdqqZ4VEyP7OU8qwZBPDqpLuFVyRzXImm8H62SmScJcmoQpPYl9Xjs2peh6qZtq5OaWyX1U1kLkEkHuZWMjOUulX0ux2n5tcq730ztZKGR2kJmXHdCIBUCZszYWNg/zZmaAAem6AFUqM/dklqfMVjAj1LNjuchwweyEVUUP8DCyEvTw7KckQChSwTSbvSMHihqMn8bRFRuxNpgoW@uiCAE0mCik2CU1DZGFoMOA2mhNJatn0c7SpgZ5rIRkLdumDSvguRgfLeB2ZPEfEUW5RFJapm0u0vRZ@wJK2pFIMpvCjJ7kZWfeVqwm1cvu4VVlWrwAoQkFsNM0hxbPWlJtSqSQ4GgebKYszoysBINSCVRHRSmcqFeYeplsW2XpLq6xebXLK@BwulWhDxeTTCgR8461/9d6VDr0XFBBrS@uWF8nJLPKzqJOOLcybVamyap9KYxXZ63MEKRqfYIoldeqbjSUIKDlYbznpYVc3MgXdWf2UMyGhciR@UoxE6Cjugtn2UQo8q/0wJBTcmTUSm@2qKt@S8iHVUvIhchmtXprt/RFsD0TBDKozRbCw6oVIcVEoFgncA0sV5V1oEbTgOZR7I3CCyeKSPNUQUvCYKxmpMqeoVoy1GxGBWY3e14ks4dTDPbNjeZLNZtbKmEX0q6U@m1m0oZmcEAjmt8rhds01hBFyNLs5vpao@MrxR9ifNm@DeT@wlqjRL8mldr6woAYFJf17CFPv@ZbpYaQvHLfKGaPkYaA49aerzftJZvf6zOcBx5@CHJ99GhrcwJUJIuGZqVZ9DY@Dho7Y@1@XN6Z2Ad99pU6aVSzerK2vyAQq9fi0dANNM8nbRO2W034pYWvwORNruWoMYwUYGBqsgm7sCadsvH12izxtPEIxv@CTkdfavbSUQVTHCjeEkW7IKx6mgMR3Rb7ul75RDm7zV3VdFb7sjqd7e05bj/2HJMB3PegOg@@8g576CrCPAduflCdClYBD7csVJXaCNuv7ezhwsy29KBOj53vkmNn2CjCbgd7rYNueEAlB1uTAVDwwaShYNLwdXIIe6dDMxPnmaoVToRgn1Dghe/7ixuxT1NepHOkuQ958dvvAA)
Total = 250 + 513 = 763.

#### How?

Builds a table with 308 entries, either 1 (identifying a noun) or 0 (identifying a non noun) and indexes into it using a key provided by a hash function that utilises the product of the ordinals of the input word:

```
OP%⁽Wpị“!ḋGẠ⁻Ṭȥʋt|Ḥ\⁾°½İ@G2ḂƑ½ịʂ¶ɦḲ⁷³Hz~⁵p9)⁹ƙ¿’B¤ - Link: list of characters, word
O                                                  - convert to ordinals
 P                                                 - product
   ⁽Wp                                             - base 250 number = 22863
  %                                                - modulo (by 22863)
                                                 ¤ - nilad plus link(s) as a nilad:
       “!ḋGẠ⁻Ṭȥʋt|Ḥ\⁾°½İ@G2ḂƑ½ịʂ¶ɦḲ⁷³Hz~⁵p9)⁹ƙ¿’   -   base 250 number
                                                B  -   as a binary list (308 bits)
      ị                                            - index into (1-indexed and modular,
                                                  -   so adds another modulo by 308)
```

---

#### Previous:  <s>50</s>  47 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 684

```
ḣ3Ẇf“QṘ°ḂżÐŒ#ḍæ09»s2¤Ȧ¬ȧØY⁾niyṖf⁽ż2ị$
0,-2ịE¬ȧÇ
```

A monadic link taking a word and returning a list of one character (truthy) if the word is identified as a noun, or an empty list or zero (both falsey) if it is not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjsXGD3e1pT1qmBP4cOeMQxse7mg6uufwhKOTlB/u6D28zMDy0O5io0NLTiw7tObE8sMzIh817svLrHy4c1rao8a9R/cYPdzdrcJloKMLYriC1bT/Bxrml1@a96hhLpiVpwvlHW63//8/MbkksyyzpBIA)** (the footer performs an if else on the result to print `Noun` or `Non-Noun`)
...or see the [scoring program](https://tio.run/##XZg/r@ZGFcZ7fwokUm5E2FR8ADoalAKlQmN7bM99xzPOzPj6vlslEWILBIpSoBTQJGgpSEEBaDcJFLsK2q9x94ssv@f4UoD0@pl5bc/MmTPnz3N842O8vn17//yr9@@/@fX05uM//Pz@xRcv/3r//NPvv3v12fef//D@@W9fPXvvJy@/rY9f/un1s5dfv/7zqy8@fPPJv1K43r/4/fTmk39@/93j@29/80733qN31fmpvfP07aunbz79mt/rZ2f7AVd3/@3f7l989eaTf/zi5Z9e/v1n3GKSR6@e/vJHH7z932f3z7989fT1s3defTZ1r57ev/gL7777@MOue/zofVbxyLoIosAXQXrz8R/PxbsfP3r88NLLL9@5f/H0/pvf3T//1b8/P/fx8NL/Cez6vLcOvPWdG0qutXPj2LmpuKCm@dK52YUEZq7ieS9Grpy84QwW78Yr7eGujF87x@uJ4Wku3E65LZomqX@1cenawkq7bd7xpNAtedeQUoJEYRrE2pOg7SvzMXfXe35M3vvF3ao/5aJmDnYvMEHvYz7AGkZf1TagaRs0h/e8GL3nvRwiUJKgaAhSdj07QVjaMC9NDfvr9xAZsFcEQFn9tRuQeNqjtdGjs8GnVly0dmfPgy9NShsWVz3o3Sb09ofZiteznPU/lCHSRH@LkDTsT6h@WHtQgoE7KqbRkKypc4x@aGrzzstZ7@Z1kzJpDbbomzqphbSrkxExo3S9XzRHKecc6RR33/rsytiNHJ3nRGo3@gFNqkE1VR0Gj37z6BoNt5KvtLdofevGwPMwTZ7tNeuFYY/qlcZboQ5ZexwzvyN1I4oa9@HSeTcsQIlXYQJQtbcT8MFsx2urJQzqbItjdh8Rxq8bE/vkV@FNFuZ9ZrKkE0es1JlaBdcTZX/@zrFr@9tn1OrvBr81NaFhG/5uk1bUpCpzpBelH3/Xil89ck5O609ulY4mDmtyWNpki02yQ4Dnoehu0MU0U3SzgL8xn8jJTToVDFkXm07Walgusz8bG5zLBbjj0iA5ouCJNXUBA2ci0UpeO6yTSfeSAvbo1TM9zigm@hUT09SzhJhzHvur7@YilwKvAP4w76lb3LoyapGfJmuuIPZh7rfo52JbrmqLQApf7NLfohdK7bD4CKxc/Mk9HrTkxnV0C05fUDmtYkXowrplfIcTRt8htSwoGTvx9G5lWEwSWu1uFMe7mx1VXVLGjMCji27dAFQH8ghtewPeje4J4N0kwM6in3hBlmxOHMOFV0PmQWioiYZdKtBprBwPV@Q62NxKoLqCXJ4fCgWqVL2yWc2x5tEXNenieSvbLT3fMfZVUmO0yVnsSVJfOj0gKToJECDJCXqdd3pwhGQWlrzG3LUuBdSSZGop8@s1Jts/XkJYaST3rJ8HyZgnfroaZ5QJagiVE4tmnS9jtJQSgvmpfHRjFM8GguXmLXA8XJM8ZPMcDU84zYzlbEu3hZkrXTpCj8LF2YzdxgFhcVsOlTW3jIZ5mFlyy9vOedGy9laI1Vc1dtIb8ZcN0tioknvXRz3OJkXJzaQo@VYxattTwBG2fUPaj/aASYCsQy4j95xJCowGUf3B64jl02vPjHTku2fwZ7Wu7L3d35m@7JFudRx45dzrEGrNWHfFE7lWgLHVgo5Q@aAujpFCDoKmbKD3JzZhnEAsXrhzImr4EzBLdl4D5oRyajj/6cldV5Xi6qo8XDM/kktVxBfo9NW2RanLemRapJQBIi9WW0m6F9DuNPlLbZ6sXZsNJpER/NUqudd9GHAOZbsqy637OGqDKNbJ3Oqe0K1Zfj0yoaE5vKhJtubuQidLIxaXoJcboVvQOiVZrlCEuqdgYWgpnV4V6gy1EwPragWFkbZYoG@LMrY1vB84YCIGxujNW1rmT2FrrZD@2iFv2WdOnqjDY0M0wLHBNDCafev2apl9r7uZiOWNQ@HocGUFqi5s6tAPNR4S/CAUAbykvR3a0WE7OtjBAmYu5pGVHiITR9DDUAVkd4GO/ap5rsxzlTM8IQN3T9hC1uH/oHOdshaXMSQ1AV9xnJVDj0pFokupHifZOi2AmB3Frjyj2QAXQzA3Vy9QrOZQME4Fszl78BxyVK/j613SHWQE5Ly9E0NSqAL2FqSnXlTKjyWTc3pvLEtDiQK9jgrQGOEo/oYB9/LIPtpyMZ@YRyEcLHJMJwPplZssOfeyyj7ni5iajg2mpuisRqvmQ0Tujot3sd1BNM7ooTze8HKi5Wg43Tjr4clKaQlzfdmJHP0uOrjjbEoHdLhE9jDoQRoZRM2wFtE1ETpxNMk6GOeyjDAY30N0LgSB/3E0oE5QzWwEkFiYTiIoFgiDU5KiJ/scdKgDuauK7aEfI4C@nhQQqga/EpVzRv10Y52UMeVf9Mk3xvz2ZiQvjaEFu5UsVA/So7ifPa2aQ1ZjKPGxOyOYxkWLQylnUTDoIe4xYKWj7WZ08JHR4YRaSac7St2johvEkGchaRXIH0FaMoyKzmOeubJY4C6Rx@IOQPEHZKWxyNNHKwOwKyZTrhz3ZuRQVxNZ5J4c30MMnM3uJ0tJfp47xWH/EQ7cGS2XtL5yYt4YobziTC/QQOL9w3D68hR/58sgx/RX8bvBABbmCA@TjADOF4wA4k2TMxuaxOWcmO4kESdlcIB3oVrMOZGuJ8spk5gQsIofzidXlFYmxYPp7N2JF4oOnkxj0mI66EluAjQDc1EOfjBmuBoXHEX8jAaKBLLBqezinjC5ycL0tBsbnJXDZiwXK5xletBCS1dzgBAZ25wjZzmbFVL3zaw8SwaRRXHEND5s3fpr/m9fr1tAVqGYRCRV1KnZOnOFxZHwFsm@KOwqXC6SYJHtiECeXJK7J/8nQcYsZLyi58JdQOQRcQAvCDK/RSlwgRkAMuIl140kFcU1vXC3mwTWZZerLnvtTQa4cSfPY37XhQma@VDrhKQqsgvoUtxTgSvUqDEIcAM9uFEhdrNr8M1OHr3I@EX3Ljrni7jEReZ2CQQD9HGB1wFhEiUdFcuiOIlNGeVKIqZiowpf0c8ip3NbjJ6KlnrRVStmYyDGsYkYRFM1n6krBshvEO0FWNACiBXpUY4fsxFaWLLKrpWyS9RxVWmzKsqZtao6WFWsr8S4VV4uYOnV2dKrGNSqQ179GAabQWTmgUOteJbxX1IwxrKGUfESn2EeKQQgNtFgK4DRhRWjF19m3qzxYs1GmhObhzWbz64KVw@mZrnOxCZt6pVbEetKgZhk2w8@TSNzT57NJiSENleDzYk/JlNZyvJ2CDPzpGzdM3PSGrvebVu5v1F4UfQtQj3SJwQlJyrqXGUd@aROZ5o6JUU@M6JNeXqTyIImhMGaHCrZ7Q6q3mT7gnQ@EBmWV20KeJsS8IapQ@BEi724eVbUYpqAsmmMKAdHObCJPAGmgy14jdDy0cZicyc2YWWrapvdu4q2Jy2dTVQcbDC2DtXXRoNR@FqN0225OTjXZsEK4l5P4q5QDm8/2futTVzCE28kngpUrdV0tKsOYCMbSAbVrdtuNL5B3xVFwGprwuY5xeLGkI3TC6rou74fWLIn1YiDqqKEy2fj9ohTvKmbRmZLY@RfhWZnpbbA7cXZq1WBnDpEZMA2UMThig7RPgcVWzNrNXmXUZ8zzqlCABimDVTeqG5StYCdVAplQBWCnLvq609UEXHyfGKeyLXEq15pm0b0Xh8yzheKRvk7VREXKyk2Q/HuRZf8EFRpEc5yQv@VLsDtobxQAaOyu8o2zC5rmJMKlSC2CyrxU3XIqOBB80Mj0IDa7DHnWC3EgUmgBS@Mj1bbKArV1eTH73l3zRJZxWiVyioFaFetHpHaqrJDNUfGM7XZzQ9BQm3KpGC0vl61M6ubHXbd7DwqmV5aMB4PFoMmNKuhvVqFE4UqdkxyuKPMhla3ss2gRCrU@8UKNAqH04FqowZMzVo9pshktf2MCrRaXqLvswTY7bsJtRHXdsq8l80sB3quiY9AVWKkjRRFZWNFBULqQiwryJrYRLNPXgoz6t2Gqj01qQTLSKqEZMFnyGpBRZDIcctKiS2rt54fOKnuLOA1GR6AurX3lpUjW1Zx18SFm7lWE4XmvtVV5eRqKENLoR5zjnbFBPekr5dU3k2l01k3UTVRgNnmbtG1It@tcVtJr0rKAJM4tPVDLPMwugyiNn3pPbT1w58k4/DjqO2hORVctgtKLvvKeWj3FFvISrEVreRSeaaceOigDzZzKPEIUMMhRwFsJTGuIyvjHdlKQithD31qA6J12e5VLP/qZf1SK9WZLin8yP8B) (counts up truthy indexes across the two lists and then calculates the score).

Score breakdown: 462 / 586 nouns correctly identified (124 incorrect), 222 / 414 non-nouns correctly identified (192 incorrect) -- total correct = 684 / 1000.

#### How?

Guess it is not a noun if...

- the last character and the character two before that are equal (with modular and 1-based indexing)
- either of the first two length 2 substrings are in:
  `'be', 'th', 'le', 'he', 'm ', 'ev', 'et', 's ', 'fl', 'ax', 'en', 'fo', 'am', 'az'` 
  (note:  `'m '` and `'s '` are only here to ease compression, but they never appear anyway)
- The -299<sup>th</sup> index (with modular and 1-based indexing) is any of:
  `aenouyz` (although this is implemented inversely and with excess capital letters)
  ...since the words all have length between 1 and 11 the -299<sup>th</sup> index is equivalent to using the length to index mapping: `{7:2; 8:5; 9:7; 11:9; else 1}`

```
ḣ3Ẇf“QṘ°ḂżÐŒ#ḍæ09»s2¤Ȧ¬ȧØY⁾niyṖf⁽ż2ị$ - Link 1: list of characters, word
ḣ3                                    - head to index 3 (1st 3 characters, like 'abc')
  Ẇ                                   - all sublists (['a','b','c','ab','bc','abc']
                    ¤                 - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
    “QṘ°ḂżÐŒ#ḍæ09»                    - compression of "bethlehem evets flaxenfoamaz"
                  s2                  - split into chunks of 2:
                                      -   be,th,le,he,m ,ev,et,s ,fl,ax,en,fo,am,az
   f                                  - filter keep (can only match 'ab' or 'bc')
                     Ȧ                - any and all (0 if empty, 1 if not)
                      ¬               - logical not
                        ØY            - consonant -y yield = "BCD...WXZbcd...wxz"
                          ⁾ni         - character pair = "ni" (no shrubbery for you!)
                             y        - translate (exchange the n for an i)
                              Ṗ       - pop (remove the z)
                       ȧ              - logical and
                                    $ - last two links as a monad:
                                ⁽ż2   -   base 250 literal = -299
                                   ị  -   index into the word
                               f      - filter keep

0,-2ịE¬ȧÇ - Main link: list of characters, word
0,-2      - pair zero with -2 = [0,-2]
    ị     - index into the word (last character and the one before the one before that)
     E    - all (both) equal?
      ¬   - logical not
        Ç - call the last link (1) as a monad
       ȧ  - logical and
```

---

13 bytes, score: 638

A first quick bash (extended above)

```
ØY⁾niyṖf⁽ż2ị$
```

Comment: `0,-2` doesn't mean `pair zero with -2` it means `literal [0, -2]`

Comment: But it's the very same effect :p

Comment: no it's not `0,-2` is a nilad, not separate `(0)(,)(-2)`...of course it's the same effect in this case but not always. I learned that the hard way...and whatever the case I'd anyways prefer to explain what actually happens instead of something with the same effect or something.

Comment: If I'd written "join" rather than "pair" would you have commented "no join is `j`"?

Comment: I might be a little bit pedantic, but `pair` or `join` are obviously wrong ways to phrase it, since `0,-2,-6` for example doesn't mean `pair 0 with -2 and then pair that with -6 = [[0, -2], -6]` but it rather means `literal [0, -2, -6]`. I get it, the `,` *atom* and the `...,...(,...(...))` *literal* are confusing...but stilll `0,-2,-6` isn't quite the same as `0,-2;-6` since the former is 1 link and the latter is 3 links.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia 34bytes, 609

`f(w)=hash(w)&0x0800000000004808>0`

I wanted to save on characters by using the in-built hash.
I feel like there must be a way to do this better.
Julia is just not friendly enough with the bit-banging operations I want to use
to make this better I think.

Finding suitable bitmasks for the hash to separate them, is an interesting game.

Comment: Best solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes, accuracy: 596

```python
lambda x:2<len(x)<7 or x[0]in"abcgmprs"or"st" in x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArzSdYDMsJgZfog5FRUmgkMKAr8e78rU3sxl@3Uek5C6Cvhgbb1Zd2xmyQN@mIzCSO59UpGIWrA0hMPRRJHADr5AkoR4/)

Simply checks first letter, length, and whether "st" is in the word
Code assumes that word is defined as x (Edit: Thanks to issacg for fixing code from snippet to function)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. While this is interesting, submissions are required to either be fuctions or full programs. This is a snippet, which is not allowed. See this [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArzSdYDMsJgZfog5FRUmgkMKAr8e78rU3sxl@3Uek5C6Cvhgbb1Zd2xmyQN@mIzCSO59UpGIWrA0hMPRRJHADr5AkoR4/ "Python 2 – Try It Online") link for a way to convert this snippet to a function while still executing the same code.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 36 bytes, <s>626</s> 631

```hs
f x=length x>2&&x!!0`notElem`"aenou"
```

Comment: 643 if anyone has a shorter language: ```length x>2&&(x!!0`notElem`"aenou"||x!!1`elem`"acqrsty")```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 50 bytes, score 602

Python isn't the most verbose language, but 50 bytes is tough.

```python
lambda x:all(x.count(y)<1for y in["ful","y","er"])
```