# Emanresu numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

My userid is 100664. In binary this is `11000100100111000`.

An interesting property of this number is that it can be created entirely by concatenating strings which are repeated at least twice:

```
11  000  100100  111  000
```

The first few such numbers are \$3,7,10,12,15,24,28,31,36,40,42, 43, 45,48,51,53,54,56,58,60,63,80,87,96,99,103,112,115,117,120,122,124,127\$ (let me know if I've missed any as I worked these out by hand).

Your challenge is to calculate these. (Leading zeros don't count, e.g. `9 = 001001` is not part of the sequence.)

As with all [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges, you may either:

- Take a number \$n\$ and output the nth term
- Take a number \$n\$ and output the first n terms
- Take no input and output these forever

[Here's a reference implementation courtesy of Bubbler](https://tio.run/##hVDNaoQwEL7nKQZ6SKYrEpVehDyJyBLZaLO1MUQPWei7u6NZLfRSQhj45vtj/GP5nFy1rm8@WLeI7fOikPR4ViKyPuhhBgVNZ52w2FR1@36HfgpgwToI2g1GlFkhJe7ofUMJqLBN2nyewiK@zEON@ru7aYi1GI0TEbNI/q/cnYqsM4N1e1zc3eLmlirYHmIjW6V4wdtDlvjIdBJRJImuv8U@JNYMNO0SM/eTFxIZJLnOII0SMzDupjj8AKc1@eXae4LEQSD01e5CSRou8LdiezIUjHZexGzOhqf6n3OkXsekGriuTw)

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

## Testcases

These are 0-indexed.

```
0 => 3
1 => 7
3 => 12
5 => 24
10 => 42
15 => 53
20 => 63
25 => 103
```

Comment: looks like 54((110110)), 58((11)(1010)) are missing.

Comment: you realise that now you can never change your username again right?

Comment: @JoKing No, I can just rename the question

Comment: Related: [Pairable strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98252/20260)

Comment: Are you going to add to OEIS?

Comment: If 3 counts `1 1` then surely 9 counts as well? `1 0 0 1`. Also are leading zeros allowed? If not you should say so in the question. Otherwise an alternative way of counting 9 is `001 001` .

Comment: @LevelRiverSt `1001` cannot be formed by concatenating strings repeated twice or more (i.e. does not match the regex `^((.+)\2+)+$`). `11` is not `1 1`, but just `11` which contains one string that has `1` repeated twice.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BŒṖŒɠṂ’ƊƇµ#
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, from STDIN and prints a list of the first \$n\$ emanresu numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//QsWS4bmWxZLJoOG5guKAmcaKxofCtSP//zMz)**

#### How?

```
BŒṖŒɠṂ’ƊƇµ# - Main Link: no arguments
          # - start with k=0 and count up, collecting the first n (from STDIN) k
              which are truthy under:
         µ  -   the monadic chain, f(k):
B           -     convert (k) to binary
 ŒṖ         -     all partitions (of the binary representation of k)
        Ƈ   -     filter - keep those (partitions) which are truthy under:
       Ɗ    -       last three links as a monad, f(partition):
   Œɠ       -         run-lengths of equal elements (e.g. 101,101,1,1,1,0 -> 2,3,1)
     Ṃ      -         minimum
      ’     -         decrement (vectorises) -> 0 is falsey, other numbers are truthy
                (a result of f(k) which is non-empty is truthy)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> 71 bytes

-7 thanks to m90, wasif, and ovs

```python
import re
i=1
while[re.match('..((.+)\\2+)+$',bin(i))and print(i)]:i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvT1pCrPCMzJzW6KFUvN7EkOUNDXU9PQ0NPWzMmxkhbU1tFXScpM08jU1MzMS9FoaAoM68EyIm1ytS2Nfz/HwA)

I feel like manually setting the index isn't optimal but idk how to avoid it in this situation.

Further optimizations:

Since bin(i) always prepends 0b to our string, and match always checks from the start, we can remove the slicing from [2:] and instead embed that in the regex.

By combining the match statement with an `and` for the print, it short circuits and only prints i if re.match returns something other than None.

And by wrapping the and statement in a list, it forces it to always be evaluated as true in our while condition.

Comment: Improvements: You can remove the slicing and put the `0b` in the regexp. The `^` can be removed since `re.match` only starts at the beginning of the string.

Comment: [72 bytes (one from m90)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvT1pCrPCMzJ1XB0KooVS83sSQ5Q0NdT09DQ09bMybGSFtTW0VdJykzTyNTUzMxL0WhoCgzrwTIsc7UtjX8/x8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvT1pCrPCMzJzW6KFUvN7EkOUNDXU9PQ0NPWzMmxkhbU1tFXScpM08jU1MzMS9FoaAoM68EyIm1ytS2Nfz/HwA) (based on wasif's suggestion)

Comment: I've added all your suggestions, really smart optimizations there.

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolSvT1pCrPCMzJzW6KFWvuDRJQ11DT1szJsZQW11HSUknTak60yqpVkkzv0ihoCgzr0QjUzPWKlPb1vD/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") by using `re.sub` instead of `re.match` allowing a simplification of the regex

Comment: @Jakque that doesn't seem to produce the same output, for example it misses 31. I'm not sure exactly what causes that, but I'd assume its overreplacing things.

Comment: @Underslash Yeah, you're right. I also thought of a lazy operator but it doesn't seems to work either

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 63 bytes

```
for(n=1;;n++)/^((.+)\2+)+$/.test(n.toString(2))&&console.log(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQy4RsjIz8CqRT9BuBiIkhW@jo@vbeE77QYyuvzt82xi0NeF@9ZyJcLgBLeDpCmharqSuwVTm0Fc7gEI2Jwl1qslUyMI7xAw)

Comment: Nice! v8 has `print`, so you can save a lot with that.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 56 bytes

```
{T`d`10`.1*$
^0*$
1$&
/^((.+)\2+)+$/&*\(`1
01
+`10
011
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/vzokISXB0CBBz1BLhSvOAEgYqqhx6cdpaOhpa8YYaWtqq@iracVoJBhyGRhyaQOVAmlDLqBOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the infinite sequence. Explanation:

```
{
```

Repeat forever.

```
T`d`10`.1*$
```

Increment the current binary value.

```
^0*$
1$&
```

If it overflows, carry the `1`.

```
/^((.+)\2+)+$/&
```

Is this an Emanresu number?

```
*\(`
```

If so then print the result of the rest of the program but then restore the current binary value.

```
1
01
+`10
011
1
```

Convert from binary to decimal.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
ℕ≜{ḃ~cḅ∋₁ᵐ&!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bGh7s6H3Ut/f@oZeqjzjnVD3c01yU/3NH6qKMbJLd1gppi7f//AA)

[Generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) numbers infinitely.

```
ℕ≜               Choose a nonnegative integer.
   ḃ             Its binary representation
    ~c           can be partitioned such that
      ḃ          if runs of equal partitions are grouped,
         ᵐ       each group
       ∋₁        has a second element.
  {       & }    Output that integer
           !     once.
```

I had hoped to use `j` here, but it can't even get close.

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>16</s></sup> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ï├1mìsM`0°ö≈
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8bc3316d8d734d6030f894f7&i=)

Prints the sequence forever.

-4 bytes using the partitioning idea.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>17</s>  15 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dudecoinheringaahing*

Takes an integer \$n\$ from STDIN and generates the first \$n\$ terms.

This is probably twice as long as it should be...

```
BŒṖ‘ḄŒɠ€ỊẸ€ẠṆø#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p6KSHO6c9apjxcEfL0UknFzxqWvNwd9fDXTtAjF0LHu5sO7xD@f9/YwMA)

Comment: Oh no, Arnauld has started writing Jelly. Soon there will be no hiding from this golfing madman. (Cool stuff, nice to see you expanding your repertoire. Sorry, I don't have any useful feedback since I don't know Jelly.)

Comment: @Etheryte Well, I wrote my first Jelly answer [almost exactly 4 years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138810/58563). But I haven't written many of them since then, that's for sure. :-p

Comment: I would've suggested [`ŒrṪ€€` \$\to\$ `Œɠ€`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p6KSHO6c9apjxcEfL0UknFzxqWvNwd9fDXTtAjF0LHu5sO7xD@f9/YwMA), but it looks like [Jonathan might have beat me to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233309/66833)

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing Thanks anyway! (Will update later.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 bytes

```perl
/^((.+)\2+)+$/&&say$.while$_=sprintf"%b",++$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18/TkNDT1szxkhbU1tFX02tOLFSRa88IzMnVSXetrigKDOvJE1JNUlJR1tbRe///3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDAE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs the first `n` terms. It's *really* annoying me that the RegEx takes up nearly ¾ of this solution but I can't seem to come up with a shorter, non-RegEx based one :\

```
È¤è"^((.+)%2+)+$"}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yKToIl4oKC4rKSUyKykrJCJ9alU&input=MTA)

```
È¤è"^((.+)%2+)+$"}jU     :Implicit input of integer U
È                        :Function taking an integer as argument
 ¤                       :  To binary string
  è                      :  Count
   "^((.+)%2+)+$"        :    RegEx /^((.+)\2+)+$/
                 }       :End function
                  jU     :Get the first U integers that return a truthy value
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>85</s> 81 bytes

```r
while(T<-T+1)grepl("^((.+)\\2+)+$",Reduce(paste0,T%/%2^(0:log2(T))%%2))&&print(T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAv0jKLlqZx@gV4TGEqMUEKTGj51tzm1zre4RIYKfWygF9phSBOYBO4rIYibJhaqb92QjSehfSyvKeGwd6jJc3YBE5N4hCpBzO8r/WDw)

A regex-based solution. Prints values indefinitely.

Thanks to @pajonk for saving 4 bytes!

Comment: Try it online! → "The permalink could not be decoded"

Comment: @KjetilS. Sorry truncated the link. Fixed now

Comment: Damn, too late. I have 82: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdLCoAgEADQyyTOoP1cRus5QOsIoiYVhEQLj2@93Uu1FucDA80tqRH9BTZxDCA3gE7huhqFqpF64fM9GOKeHx40iV6YDYYp3NYAIQphEDG7u/yr9QM "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk are you happy for me to use your `Reduce`? I can get 81 provided the `print` output from R is allowed.

Comment: Combined makes 81: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAz2TuopV5jM4@oLMIUYsJUmJGz7fmNrnW9wiRwMydESP6TCkCdwC9QGu1QNFwudD@bARpvQspadjAtAM1xctrMIiMacS2TTmc5X@tHw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Nick, yes, the Reduce trick is I think standard. As I recall I know it from the R tips question.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒb.œ2ìεγ€g2@P}à
```

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSYi7FkzLDrM61zrPigqxnMkBQfcOg//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞              # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ             # Filter this list by:
  b            #  Convert the current integer to binary
   .œ          #  Get all partitions of this binary string
     2ì        #  Prepend a 2 before each part (this is necessary because `γ` will
               #  ignore leading 0s, and thus incorrectly group "1" and "01" together)
       ε       #  Map each partition to:
        γ      #   Group adjacent equivalent elements together
         €g    #   Get the length of each group
           2@  #   Check for each length if it's >= 2
             P #   Check if all are truthy (by taking the product)
       }à      #  After the map: check if any partition is truthy (by taking the max)
               # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 23 bytes

```
λbvS∑`^((.+)\\2+)+$`r;ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%CE%BBbvS%E2%88%91%60%5E%28%28.%2B%29%5C%5C2%2B%29%2B%24%60r%3B%C8%AF&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

A juicy port of JavaScript. Man I do love me some regex in golfing languages. Takes `n` and outputs the first n terms.

Comment: Someone should invent a compressed regex golfing language

Comment: Retinaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: @Razetime Retina sucks at sequence challenges though, since it has no repeat-until loops.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
ΠøṖ'ĠvḢA)ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLOoMO44bmWJ8SgduG4okEpyK8iLCIiLCIxMCJd)

Port of Jelly.

-2 bytes thanks to emanresu A and lyxal

Comment: [11](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiaxiw7jhuZYnxKDDnmfhuKI7yK8iLCIiLCIzMyJd)

Comment: this can be [10 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLOoMO44bmWJ8SgduG4okEpyK8iLCIiLCIxMCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 65 bytes

```julia
!i=replace(bitstring(i+=1),r"((.+)\2+)"=>"")>""||println(i),!i;!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHTtii1ICcxOVUjKbOkuKQoMy9dI1Pb1lBTp0hJQ0NPWzPGSFtTydZOSUkTiGtqCoAqSnLyNDI1dRQzrRUN//8HAA)

Comment: 58 is missing. 58=111010. Don't know why but some of the other answers have `^` and `+$` at the start and end of the regex.

Comment: good catch! I might have to add it too